# Is the inverse image of a Cauchy sequence of a continuous and injective function a Cauchy sequence?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two metric spaces

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a continuous and injective function

Let $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X$ be a sequence in $X$ such that the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset Y$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Is it true that $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence too ?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the function $\tanh : \Bbb R\to (-1,1)$ or $\frac1x : \Bbb R_{>0}\to \Bbb R_{>0}$. Both of these maps are actually homeomorphisms for which the statement fails.

Comment: @s.harp I am sorry, I did not read your comment carefully enough. I just read $\tanh$ part. If you wish, I delete my answer.

Comment: @Severin no need to delete anything! I just added some more thoughts to the comment as I thought of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in general. Let $X=Y=\mathbb R$. Assume that in $X$ you have the discrete metric and that in $Y$ you have the usual one. Let $f$ be the identity map and consider the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. It is not a Cauchy sequence in $X$, but it is the preimage of $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, which *is* a Cauchy sequence in $Y$.

Comment: thanks for your aswers

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Another example would be $X=Y=(0,\infty)$ both with the euclidean metric. Consider $ f(x) = 1/x$. Then the sequence $(1/n)_{n\geq 1}$ is Cauchy, but the preimage $(n)_{n\geq 1}$ is not.